# Strange characters in Batch file CMD screen

Tags: windows

I have a batch script to copy files from one location to another, on running it is showing strange characters on screen when ran.Also it is showing all the files copied in one line. I want to remove the strange characters and to show files copied properly in next line.

Please note: Output have no issue. Only command screen have issue.

Please help!!!
[image: Batch CMD screen]

```
SET DATE=%date:~4,2%/%date:~7,2%/%date:~10,4%
set /p DATE_FROM="Pls Enter From DATE (MM/DD/yyyy):- "

set /p DATE_TO="Pls Enter To Date(MM/DD/yyyy) :- "
set fdate=%date_from:~0,2%%date_from:~3,2%%date_from:~6,4%-%date_to:~0,2%%date_to:~3,2%%date_to:~6,4%
set time=%time::=%
PUSHD \\sdpw9100app\work
> nul forfiles /P \Advice\LogFile  /D +%DATE_FROM% /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE 2> nul forfiles /M  @file /D -%DATE_TO% && > con (cmd /c xcopy /S /Y @path c:\temp\ZodiacLogs\ops_logs_%fdate%\%computername%\Advice\)"

POPD
```

Comment: It is CR (carriage return, 0x0D, note char) and LF (linefeed, 0x0A, circle-in-square char). They are "non-printable" symbols, in common their combination must be interpreted in Windows console as linebreak. If they are typed as shown there is some problem in your console settings.

Comment: Hi Akina. Thanks for quick reply... I tried this batch in multiple machines.. same issue observed everywhere.. I checked the console setting as well nothing found related.. Please let me know how to solve this issue

Comment: It is very difficult to heal by the photo. Post your batch file (or the line which gives such output at least) as a text.

Comment: I added the batch code.. Don't know how to add in text.

Comment: Edit the code, add 4 or more spaces before each code line...

Comment: Hi Akina.. Code is edited.. can you please check the issue now.